# get seleceted dropdown option value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, drop-down-menu, selected

I have two dropdowns -- for the month and year -- and a button. When the user clicks the button, I want to grab the selected month value and year value and pass them as query string to a URL like this: `https://mysite.com/events.aspx?my=may2012`.

How do I grab those values using jQuery or Javascript?

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div class="calendForm">
    <span class="inpMonth">
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">September</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>July</option>
        <option>June</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>March</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option>January</option>
        <option>December</option>
        <option>November</option>
        <option>October</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="inpYear">
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">2012</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
        <option>2015</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <a href="#" type="submit" class="btnBlue"><span>GO</span></a>
</div><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in T. Stone's answer. the selector should have a dot. 
Other than that - great answer!

[See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tRMB/2/)

```
<script>
$(function(){$(".btnBlue").click(function(){
    window.location = "https://mysite.com/events.aspx?my=" + $(".inpMonth select").val().toLowerCase() + $(".inpYear select").val();
})})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want this all to happen on the click event of `btnBlue`.

Start with a click handler...

```
$('a.btnBlue').click(function() {
   // ...
});
```

Then get the values of the month/year...

```
var month = $('.inpMonth select').val();
var year = $('.inpYear select').val();
```

Then navigate to that URL...

```
window.location.href = 'https://mysite.com/events.aspx?my=' + month + year;
```

All together that's...

```
$('a.btnBlue').click(function() {
    var month = $('.inpMonth select').val();
    var year = $('.inpYear select').val();
    window.location.href = 'https://mysite.com/events.aspx?my=' + month + year;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first, get references to your SELECT and LINK dom objects:

```
var button = $('a.btnBlue');
var month = $('#datepicker .inpMonth select');
var year = $('#datepicker .inpYear select');
```

next, create a function to return the current month & year as a string:

```
function currentSelection() {
  return month.val() + year.val();
}
```

create a function which navigates you to the new url based on currentSelection():

```
function navigateToDate() {
  window.location.href = "https://mysite.com/events.aspx?my=" + currentSelection();
}
```

when the button is clicked, call navigateToDate():

```
button.click( navigateToDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the month try

```
$(".inpMonth select").val();
```

To parse a whole form give .serialize() and .serializeArray() a try

```
$("form").serialize()
```