# Using jQuery global variable in href parameter

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu, selected

I have a problem using the selected value from a form in jquery.
It is closely related to:

- [Get selected value of a dropdown's item using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery).
- [get seleceted dropdown option value jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718645/get-seleceted-dropdown-option-value-jquery).

I have tried for hours getting this work using the above (and other) examples.

I have a drop down list with account numbers:

```
    <form id="accounts">
        <select>
            <option value="">Select one</option>
            <c:forEach var="custAccount" items="${customerAccounts}">
                <option value=${customerAccount}>${customerAccount.accountId}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </form>
```

I want to use the selected account in an href:

```
            <a href="Controller?&accountid='+selectedAccount+'&username=${username}&userid=${userid}&command=customerNewTransaction">Start new transfer</a>
```

And here is my script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var selectedAccount;
        $("#accounts").change(function() {
           selectedAccount = $(this).text();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

This doesn't work and the selected text is empty every time. I have also tried calling .val() aswell with the same (lack of) result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Change `$("#accounts")` to `$("#accounts select")`, although it'll probably be better if you gave the actual `<select>` element an ID (*not* the form), thus `<select id="account-select">` for `$('#account-select');`

Comment: Ok. But what about the href - How do I use the var "selectedAccount"?

Comment: You cannot use a JavaScript variable in the middle of HTML like in your question, have to first render some HTML, then change it with JS later. See both of our answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="accounts">
    <select id="account-select">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <c:forEach var="custAccount" items="${customerAccounts}">
            <option value=${customerAccount}>${customerAccount.accountId}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <div id="transfer-container">

    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#account-select").change(function() {
          $('#transfer-container').html( '<a href="Controller?&accountid='+ $(this).val() +'">Start new transfer</a>' );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added an change handler on the form, instead of the select. You might want something like this:

```
<form id="accountForm">
  <select id="account">
    ..
  </select>
</form>
```

and then in your jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#account').on('change', function (event) {
      $('#accountForm').append($(this).val());
    });        
});
```

Comment: what will .append accomplish? sorry if its a dumb question

Comment: I did not quite understand what you wanted to achieve with: selectedAccount = $(this).text(); Append adds the value of the dropdown (i.e. the selected option) to the form.

Comment: The form itself was a fault on my part - it is unnecessary since the only place I need the text from the selection is in the href. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see MackieeE beat me to it, but just to offer a slightly different example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateLink() {
            var selectedAccount = $('#account').val();
            var uri = 'Controller?&accountid='+selectedAccount+'&command=customerNewTransaction';

            $('#account-link').attr('href', uri);
        }
    </script>

    <form>
      <select id="account" onchange="updateLink();">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Select one</option>
        <c:forEach var="custAccount" items="${customerAccounts}">
          <option value=${customerAccount}>${customerAccount.accountId}</option>
        </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </form>

    <a id="account-link" href="#">Start a new transfer</a>
```